# button not aligned with image in div

Tags: css

In the following image , the button (Questions) is lower than the image (white rectangle). They both are inside the same div. Why? The page has a top level `css-grid` with 3 rows.

[image]

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: [nav-row-start]auto [nav-row-end logo-nav-row-start] auto [logo-nav-row-end content-row-start] auto [content-row-end];
}

.nav-style {
  height: 5vh;
  /*make nav div take 5% of space of viewport*/
  background-color: black;
}

.logo-nav-style {
  height: 20vh;
  /*make logo-nav div take 20% of space of viewport*/
  background-color: gray;
}

.nav-flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.content-style {
  height: 75vh;
  /*make content div take 75% of space of viewport*/
  background-color: white;
}

#nav {
  grid-row: nav-row-start/nav-row-end;
  margin: 0px;
}

#logo-nav {
  grid-row: logo-nav-row-start/logo-nav-row-end;
  margin: 0px;
}

#content {
  grid-row: body-row-start/body-row-end;
  margin: 0px;
}

#profile-pic {
  margin: 5px;
}

#mail-icon-pic {
  margin: 5px;
}

#stats-icon-pic {
  margin: 5px;
}

#logo-image {
  /*the max width and max height rule will make the image fit inside the div. If the image is bigger than div, the image will
    contract, if the image is smaller than the div, the image will expand*/
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="nav" class="nav-style nav-flexbox-container">
    <img id="stats-icon-pic" src="stats_icon.png">
    <img id="mail-icon-pic" src="mail_icon.png">
  </div>
  <div id="logo-nav" class="logo-nav-style">
    <img id="logo-image" src="example_logo.png"/>
    <button type="button">Questions</button>
    <!-- this button is lower than the image-->
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="content-style">body</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because the image with `id="logo-image"` blocks the button out of the original context.

Comment: sorry, not following you. Could you please elaborate.

Comment: are you talking about `position` attribute of the `button`? I have tried various values but I can't make the button align with the  image.

Comment: I want it to be at the bottom, in line with the bottom of the image. but it is right not bit more lower than that

Comment: Remove height: 20vh in .logo-nav-style class. I can't reproduce since there is no images.

Comment: I need 20vh as that is how I have divided the page into different sections

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't answer the "why" part, but one solution is to add `display: flex` and `align-items: flex-end` to `.logo-nav-style`.

Also, I wouldn't lock `.content-style` to `height: 75vh` but use `min-height: 75vh` instead so the content can expand beyond that.

I'm also confused why you got `flex-direction: row-reverse;` on your `.nav-flexbox-container`. Why not just put the elements in the correct order to begin with?

```css
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: [nav-row-start]auto [nav-row-end logo-nav-row-start] auto [logo-nav-row-end content-row-start] auto [content-row-end];
}

.nav-style {
  height: 5vh;
  /*make nav div take 5% of space of viewport*/
  background-color: black;
}

.logo-nav-style {
  height: 20vh;
  /*make logo-nav div take 20% of space of viewport*/
  background-color: gray;

  /* Rickard's addition */
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.nav-flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.content-style {
  min-height: 75vh;
  /*make content div take 75% of space of viewport*/
  background-color: white;
}

#nav {
  grid-row: nav-row-start/nav-row-end;
  margin: 0px;
}

#logo-nav {
  grid-row: logo-nav-row-start/logo-nav-row-end;
  margin: 0px;
}

#content {
  grid-row: body-row-start/body-row-end;
  margin: 0px;
}

#profile-pic {
  margin: 5px;
}

#mail-icon-pic {
  margin: 5px;
}

#stats-icon-pic {
  margin: 5px;
}

#logo-image {
  /*the max width and max height rule will make the image fit inside the div. If the image is bigger than div, the image will
    contract, if the image is smaller than the div, the image will expand*/
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-container">
  <div id="nav" class="nav-style nav-flexbox-container">
    <img id="stats-icon-pic" src="stats_icon.png">
    <img id="mail-icon-pic" src="mail_icon.png">
  </div>
  <div id="logo-nav" class="logo-nav-style">
    <img id="logo-image" src="example_logo.png"/>
    <button type="button">Questions</button>
    <!-- this button is lower than the image-->
  </div>
  <div id="content" class="content-style">body</div>
</div>
```